# Base change of a hypercovering

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a topos and $U_\bullet$ be a hypercovering of $X$. Could someone explain me what does it mean to say

1) Changing the base of the hypercovering $U_\bullet$ to $U_0$ (where $U_0$ is the first level of the hypercover)?

2) And what does it mean to say that this change of base gives a section ?

Comment: What is $U_0$? You mean the literal first level of the hypercovering? If this is the topos on a site with a standard étale pretopology, then I'd imagine it just comes from base changing the covering at every level to $U_0$. For 2), I don't know precisely, but I would imagine it's similar to the following situation. If you're dealing with the site $X_{\text{Fet}}$ then any element $U\to X$ has a finite étale cover $V\to X$ such that $U\times_X V\to V$ is trivial (and so has multiple sections).